# Why dont i lag on my first chunk load but i do on my last?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I have a procedural generated game using a perlin map. Iv made it where it only loads the tiles of the area your at, and when you leave that area it deletes them and re draws them according to where you walked too. So theoretically it should only load the tiles of the area you are at. But it seems the further into my map you walk the more it begins to lag. Tho im not sure why since it should never be loading a different amount of blocks.

Here is a link to the game as of now.
http://www.fastswf.com/nzpBar0

These are the functions that are adding and deleting the tiles.

```
    //deletes the tiles on the world.
    public function deleteTiles()
    {
        if (tilesInWorld.length > 0)
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < tilesInWorld.length; i++)
            {
                worldTiles.removeChild(tilesInWorld.pop());
            }
            generateTile();
        }
    }
    //generates the tiles on the world
    public function generateTile()
    {
        for (var i:int = X/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; i < (X + (800/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE); i++)
        {
            for (var j:int = Y/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; j < Y + (600/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; j++)
            {
                hm = heightmap[i][j];
                if (hm >= 0.84)
                {
                    tile = new Water();
                }
                else if (hm >= 0.8 && hm < 0.84)
                {
                    tile = new Shallow();
                }
                else if (hm >= 0.7 && hm < 0.8)
                {
                    tile = new Sand();
                }
                else if (hm >= 0.2 && hm < 0.7)
                {
                    tile = new Tile();
                }
                else
                {
                    tile = new Stone();
                }
                tile.width = TILE_SIZE;
                tile.height = TILE_SIZE;
                worldTiles.x = 0;
                worldTiles.y = 0;
                tile.x = TILE_SIZE * (i % 800);
                tile.y = TILE_SIZE * (j % 600);
                tilesInWorld.push(tile);
                worldTiles.addChild(tile);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where the perlin map and the first tile area is created

```
    public function World(parentMC:MovieClip)
    {
        TILE_SIZE = GlobalCode.TILE_SIZE;
        map_width = GlobalCode.MAP_WIDTH;
        map_height = GlobalCode.MAP_HEIGHT;
        pmap = new BitmapData(map_width,map_height);
        grid_width = new uint(map_width / TILE_SIZE);
        grid_height = new uint(map_height / TILE_SIZE);
        //map_width = GlobalCode.MAP_WIDTH;
        //map_height = GlobalCode.MAP_HEIGHT;
        pmap.perlinNoise(map_width,map_height, 6, _seed, true, false, 1, true);
        for (var i:uint=0; i < grid_width; i++)
        {
            heightmap[i] = new Array();
            for (var j:uint=0; j < grid_height; j++)
            {
                heightmap[i][j] = new uint();
            }
        }
        //Divide the map in to a 7x7 grid and take data at each interval
        for (i = 0; i < grid_width; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < grid_height; j++)
            {
                pixelPoint.x = Math.round((i/grid_width) * pmap.width)+1;
                pixelPoint.y = Math.round((j/grid_width) * pmap.height)+1;
                heightmap[i][j] = pmap.getPixel(pixelPoint.x,pixelPoint.y);
                heightmap[i][j] /=  0xffffff;

                if (heightmap[i][j] < darkest_pixel)
                {
                    darkest_pixel = heightmap[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        //Adjust values to a min of 0
        for (i = 0; i < grid_width; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < grid_height; j++)
            {
                heightmap[i][j] -=  darkest_pixel;

                if (heightmap[i][j] > brightest_pixel)
                {
                    brightest_pixel = heightmap[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        //Adjust values to highest value of 1
        for (i = 0; i < grid_width; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < grid_height; j++)
            {
                heightmap[i][j] /=  brightest_pixel;
            }
        }
        worldTiles = new Sprite();
        parentMC.addChild(worldTiles);
        generateTile();
    }
```

this is what creats the scroll rect and the X/Y changes when you walk to the edge of a screen.

```
    public function update(e:Event)
    {
        world.worldTiles.scrollRect = new Rectangle(X,Y,800,600);
        if (canMove == true)
        {
            MovePlayer();
        }
        player.update();
        PlayerOnTile();
    }
```

And for giggles this is what moves my character and the scroll/rect

```
    protected function MovePlayer()
    {
        if (goin[0] == 1)
        {
            player.y -=  moveSpeed;
            if (player.y <= 0 && (Yloc) > 0)
            {
                world.Y -= int(600/world.TILE_SIZE)/MAP_SCALE;
                world.deleteTiles();
                Y -=  600 / MAP_SCALE;
                Yloc -=  1;
                player.y +=  600;
            }
        }
        if (goin[1] == 1)
        {
            player.y +=  moveSpeed;
            if (player.y >= 600 && (Yloc + 1) < MAP_SCALE)
            {
                world.Y += int(600/world.TILE_SIZE)/MAP_SCALE;
                world.deleteTiles();
                Y +=  600 / MAP_SCALE;
                Yloc +=  1;
                player.y -=  600;
            }
            //world.worldTiles.y -=  moveSpeed;
        }
        if (goin[2] == 1)
        {
            player.x -=  moveSpeed;
            if (player.x <= 0 && (Xloc) > 0 )
            {
                world.X -= int(800/world.TILE_SIZE)/MAP_SCALE;
                world.deleteTiles();
                X -=  800 / MAP_SCALE;
                Xloc -=  1;
                player.x +=  800;
            }
            //world.worldTiles.x +=  moveSpeed;
        }
        if (goin[3] == 1)
        {
            player.x +=  moveSpeed;
            if (player.x >= 800&& (Xloc + 1) < MAP_SCALE)
            {
                world.X += int(800/world.TILE_SIZE)/MAP_SCALE;
                world.deleteTiles();
                X +=  800 / MAP_SCALE;
                Xloc +=  1;
                player.x -= 800;
            }
            //world.worldTiles.x -=  moveSpeed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see it lagging. There's some problem with the key press, as sometimes it's not actually working, and sometimes happens instantly. Sometimes (after 30 seconds of clicking and so a lot of tiles loaded), it works almost instantly. You code is way too much in order to find any issue - minimize the possible errors and ask more defined question :)

Comment: my codes not THAT messy :c

But thats strange, iv never had a key pressing issue while testing it... very interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple and basic. You are creating new objects constantly and after a while your app can't get enough memory to create new object and also needs to use big chunk of CPU power to clean up. All this produces lag and is a form of memory leak. You need to reuse object instead of creating new ones. This process is called Object Pooling. Once a graphic is not needed, instead of discarding it and creating a new one next time, you keep it and reuse it next time. That way you don't need additional memory and your app doesn't need more and doesn't need to clean up as much (called garbage collection).

```
public function deleteTiles()
{
    if (tilesInWorld.length)
    {            
        for (var i:int = 0; i < tilesInWorld.length; i++)
        {
            worldTiles.removeChild(tilesInWorld[i]);//no new object creation when deleting
            //tilesInWorld.pop() create a new array internally
        }
        tilesInWorld.length = 0;//empty array
        generateTile();//this should be improved too
    }
}
```

if worldTiles holds only titles then worldTiles.removeChildren() will do it as:

```
worldTiles.removeChildren();
tilesInWorld.length = 0;
generateTile();
```

Comment: That makes alot of since, ill check into object pooling and do this.

Comment: He removes them as children, so they get collected by the garbage collector. And they are like a hundred, so this is not that big issue I think. You are right it's better to use pooling, but I don't think it's harming the performance that much.

Comment: this is a very repetitive pattern of creation of new object and deletion of old one. Quantity and type of these object is irrelevant. He ends up overloading memory allocation and garbage collection and starts lagging pretty quick I bet. The more he will let the application run the more lag and drop of fps he will experience. As an example a simple array.pop() creates a new array and so is another memory allocation.

Comment: TO clear it up, it doesnt lag on my pc. But i want this to run on low end pc's also. My girl friends lap top and my friends low end pc lag pretty bad 3 squares left and 3 squares down +.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how Actionscript handles it, but it might be your for loop in the deleteTiles() function. It only continues until i < tilesInWorld.length, and every iteration of the for loop your i increases by one, and your tilesInWorld decreases by one. This means that you'd only be deleting half of the tiles every time you try to remove all the tiles.

Try using a while loop instead, and see if that fixes it. e.g.

```
public function deleteTiles()
{
    if (tilesInWorld.length > 0)
    {
        while (tilesInWorld.length > 0)
        {
            worldTiles.removeChild(tilesInWorld.pop());
        }
        generateTile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why cant i give 2 replies a green check :D o well, what u said makes since and i should of probably been using a while loop in the first place regardless of it that helps or not